# Trying to get Python to control Firefox

Tags: python, selenium

I have only been learning Python for a couple of weeks.
I am trying to control Firefox with Python via Selenium and geckodriver, Winddow 10
I have stored geckodriver in `c:\Users\david\Downloads\`
I have used this script in Thonny (I have included the Selenium package from Thonny)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="c:/Users/david/Downloads/geckodriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

I receive this

> SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of
>   capabilities errorhandler.py, line 242
>
> and
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\david\Documents\Junk\web control.py", line 4, in 
>       driver = webdriver.Firefox()   File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py",
>   line 174, in **init**
>       keep_alive=True)   File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 157, in **init**
>       self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)   File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 252, in start_session
>       response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)   File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 321, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
>   line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable
>   to find a matching set of capabilities

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possibly a mismatch of webdriver vs browser. What is your geckodriver and mozilla ff version?

Comment: provide details on GeckoDriver version and firefox browser version

Comment: remove line 'driver = webdriver.Firefox()', try it again.

Comment: Mozilla: 75.0 (64-bit)

Comment: geckodriver-v0.26.0-win32

Comment: Tried that, no difference